# (C) Dancing Cursor while waiting for input

Tags: c, loops, cursor, exit

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define WAIT 25000000
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int exit = 0;

    while (exit == 0) {
        printf("\\");
        for (i = 0; i < WAIT; i++);
        printf("\b");
        for (i = 0; i < WAIT; i++);
        printf("|");
        for (i = 0; i < WAIT; i++);
        printf("\b");
        for (i = 0; i < WAIT; i++);
        printf("/");
        for (i = 0; i < WAIT; i++);
        printf("\b");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make one of those cursors that "move" while waiting for user input, but right now I don't know how to stop it, or well I'd prefer that it takes the place of the normal cursor in terminal. How do you do this?

Comment: check return of like `kbhit()` then break;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define WAIT 25000


void waitCursor() {

    while(!kbhit()) {

        printf("\\");
        usleep(WAIT);
        printf("\b");
        usleep(WAIT);
        printf("|");
        usleep(WAIT);
        printf("\b");
        usleep(WAIT);
        printf("/");
        usleep(WAIT);
        printf("\b");
        usleep(WAIT);

    }

    printf("User pressed a key! waitCursor stopped\n");

}

int main() {


    waitCursor();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this takes tooo long to respond to a keystroke.  instead, put all the characters into an array, including the backspaces '\b'.  Then the loop becomes int i = 0; while (!kbhit()) { printf( "%c", array[i]); usleep(WAIT); i = (i++)%(sizeof array/ sizeof char); }